# Faking a network communication to test client/server on one computer

Tags: c, networking, tcp, udp, ip

I have a course project where I'm suppose to present some networking stuff. There are great chances that I have to do it on one computer. So my question is, how do I show a communication between tcp/ip or tcp/udp? I'm not a networking expert, I understand the concept of sending data which is red. And I think I need two IP addresses.

Answer (score 9):

You don't need two IP addresses.  Just start the server on the machine, and have the client connect to address 127.0.0.1 and the appropriate port.  (This address always refers to the same machine the program is running on.)

Answer (score 1):

You can run a virtual machine on your computer and work on network between them.